# How to reference a composite primary key?

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have two tables, 'warehouse_item' which has a primary composite key 'warehouse_id , store_id', and I have a 'store' table which I want to connect to the previous table using a FK. I understand that the FK has to be composite too, I tried the code below, but it didn'tt achieve the task.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS warehouse_item;
CREATE TABLE warehouse_item
(warehouse_id varchar(3) NOT NULL,
store_id varchar(3) NOT NULL,
product_id varchar(5) NOT NULL,
product_qty integer NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (warehouse_id,store_id)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS store;
CREATE TABLE store
(store_id varchar(3) NOT NULL,
store_name varchar(30) NOT NULL,
store_city varchar(15) NOT NULL,
store_address varchar(50) NOT NULL,
telephone varchar(15) NOT NULL,
latitude decimal NOT NULL,
longitude decimal NOT NULL,
warehouse_id varchar(3) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (store_id),
FOREIGN KEY (store_id,warehouse_id) REFERENCES warehouse_item (warehouse_id, store_id)
);
```

Comment: The order of attributes in the foreign key definition is swapped, `foreign key (store_id, warehouse_id) REFERENCES warehouse_item (warehouse_id, store_id)`. Should be `foreign key (warehouse_id, store_id) REFERENCES warehouse_item (warehouse_id, store_id)`

Comment: It sounds to me like you need a foreign key from warehouse_item to store, and not the other way around. The field warehouse_id in store seems to be superfluous. Also, it seems to me the primary key of warehouse_item should be (warehouse_id, store_id, product_id), otherwise you can only have one product per store/warehouse.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm i dont think the order plays a role, i changed it as you said but it didnt work.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel and how would the FK in the warehouse_item table look like ? should i references only the "store_id" ?

Comment: @lucakramp You need to define a primary key on store.store_id and then define a foreign key from warehouse_item.store_id to store.store_id.

Answer (score 0):

Store table doesn't need a composite key that derives from warehouse. It is the warehouse and only the warehouse that depends on the existence of the store and not the other way around.

Delete any attributes of the warehouse in the store table, you don't need them in there. If you need to find the store via the warehouse just look at the stor_id field in its table; and if you need to find the warehouse from the store just find the stores which have the store_id in them.